# Set initial axis limits while preserving pan/zoom in DearPyGui

Tags: python, dearpygui

Using DearPyGui, the x-axis and y-axis limits of a plot can be set using the `dpg.set_axis_limits` function, i.e.

```
dpg.set_axis_limits("xaxis", xmin, xmax)
dpg.set_axis_limits("yaxis", ymin, ymax)
```

This *does* set the limits of the respective axis, but it also prevents the plot from being panned or zoomed like is available by default in a DearPyGui plot (when `dpg.set_axis_limits` is **not** used).

Is it possible to set the *initial axis limits* of a DearPyGui plot (similar to above) but still have the ability to pan and zoom beyond the *initial* axis limits?

Note: due to the structure of my data, relying on auto-formatting via `dpg.set_axis_limits_auto` does not work for setting the initial plot view.